# Two-dimensional list which contains strings and integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a two-dimensional list; i.e. a nested list, which contains integers and strings.

```
mylist = [[92, "james"], [88, "john"], [75, "robert"], [80, "michael"], [25, "william"], [54, "david"], [59, "richard"], [74, "charles"], [46, "joseph"], [90, "thomas"], [80, "christopher"]]
```

I want to a way to go through the strings only, check if they start with a particular letter; say `j`, delete it and ignore the rest of the elements that don't meet this condition.

The desired result will look like this:

```
mylist = [[92, "ames"], [88, "ohn"], [75, "robert"], [80, "michael"], [25, "william"], [54, "david"], [59, "richard"], [74, "charles"], [46, "oseph"], [90, "thomas"], [80, "christo, her"]]
```

Comment: I tried using a traditional for loop, however, I have a problem iterating over integers in the list.

Comment: @AkbarHussein post the code you've tried so far, and explain what goes wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is a solution using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist = [[num, (name[1:] if name[0] == "j" else name)]
          for num, name in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `lstrip()` to remove leading characters:

```
[[i, j.lstrip('j')] for i, j in mylist]
```